# Question on Variables and Ability to reference in next steps

Tags: powershell

```
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -IgnoreDefaultScope
```

Does the line above simply mean I'm running *the command* and piping ALL of its output into a variable called $groups so I can do things with it later?

Read MS websites but not found clear answer.

Comment: You're not _piping_ the output, you're _assigning_ it to `$groups`. But other than that, the answer is yes. See [`about_Assignment_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators)

Comment: In general, the assignment captures what is listed under the [Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps#outputs) section of the reference. In this case it just links to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/management/exchange-management-shell-cmdlet-input-and-output-types , where you have to search for `Get-DistributionGroup` again(!), to find out its possible output types. To find out what type you actually got in `$groups`, insert the line `$groups.GetType().Fullname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes.

To discover exactly what is within variable you can pipe it to get-member and check its TypeName, properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

So the line above DOES simply mean I'm running the command and "piping" (or rather assigning) ALL of its output into a variable called $groups so I can do things with it later.
Thank you all for your feedback. Appreciate it.